# API индексов Укрпочты

Tags: поиск-api

Нужен API для поиска индексов Укрпочты.

Вручную искать можно тут - https://ukrposhta.ua/dovidka/indeksi/ , но мне нужно проверить довольно большое к-во индексов.

На сколько понимаю, запрос с индексом отправляется вот сюда - https://a.ukrposhta.ua/map/mapserver-new.php

Но отправить точно такой же запрос через POST-запрос не получилось, ответ не приходит.

Comment: https://109.te.ua/230 и просто распарсить

Comment: @KoVadim в том то и проблема, что база индексов у нас есть. но нужно исключить те, которые находятся на неподконтрольной территории и на данный момент не работают. это можно получить только с сайта УП.

Comment: там буквально рядом на странице есть три документа, где есть текущий список населенных пунктов https://ukrposhta.ua/robota-ukrposhti-v-doneckij-ta-luganskij-oblastyax/ Да, нужно немного ручками поработать, но это на час максимум